# Select project children on parent select

Tags: sdk, rally

I am implementing a project picker for a Rally custom app and would like to select a projects children automatically when the parent is selected from the picker. I was able to get the ObjectID and Name of the objects I want to select but can't seem to get them to be selected from the picker. I attempted this using the "fireEvent" method but had no success. Here's what I have so far:

```
var teamPick = this.down('#filterPanel').add({
    xtype: 'rallymultiobjectpicker',
    id: 'teams',
    modelType: 'project',
    fieldLabel: 'Teams',
    listeners: {
        select: function(field, selected) {
            Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
                autoLoad: true,
                fetch: [ 'Name', 'ObjectID' ],
                filters: [
                    { property: 'Parent.ObjectID', value: selected.ObjectID }
                ],
                model: 'Project',
                listeners: {
                    load: function(store, data) {
                        Ext.Array.each(data, function(child) {
                            console.log(child.get('Name')); //Logs the child name
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        },
        scope: this
    }
});
```

Comment: I am trying to achieve something on similar lines, did this issue resolve for you? Can you explain it here please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this without the use of the fireEvent method. Instead, I used the getValue and setValue methods and added the child projects to the state manually:

```
    this.down('#filters').add({
        xtype: 'rallymultiobjectpicker',
        id: 'teams',
        modelType: 'project',
        listeners: {
            blur: function() { this.down('#teams').collapse(); },
            select: function(field, selected) {
                Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
                    autoLoad: true,
                    fetch: [ 'Name', 'ObjectID' ],
                    filters: [
                        { property: 'Parent.ObjectID', value: selected.ObjectID }
                    ],
                    model: 'Project',
                    listeners: {
                        load: function(store, data) {
                            var selected = this.down('#teams').getValue();
                            Ext.Array.each(data, function(child) {
                                selected.push(child.data);
                            });
                            this.down('#teams').setValue(selected);
                        },
                        scope: this
                    }
                });
            }
            scope:    this
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using 2.0p3?  There was a known issue with events not being correctly fired in the MultiObjectPicker.  This should be resolved in 2.0p4.  I ran your code in a 2.0p4 app and it functioned as expected.

As a side note your child project query can be written like this as well:

```
filters: [
    { property: 'Parent', value: '/project/' + selected.ObjectID }
]
```

The 2.0p4 version of the component also added a new event called selectionchange which gives you an array of the currently selected values (since it is a multi select picker).  There are individual select and deselect events that fire when a specific item is selected/deselected.

Comment: How would I go about selecting which object to fire the event on? I have the raw name of the field, but how can I select it to correctly target the event?